# Class removed when at media break

Tags: javascript, css

I have minified my code to the basics I have a nav bar that slides up and the and down on scroll, everything functions as it should the problem area is I hide it at 990 breakpoint and if you scroll at that break point then go full screen it removes one of the classes called active, then if I start to scroll it goes back to normal. is there any way to force that class back in the JavaScript?

to show the issue scroll down and you'll see the nav work then shrink screen and scroll you will see nothing since I didn't add the code for it. but then go full screen after scrolling in mobile and you will see that active does not get added back to siteHeader after scrolling in mobile.

```js
(function($) {
  var header = $('.siteHeader');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
      header.addClass('fixed active').off('transitionend');  
    } else if (header.hasClass('active')) {
      header.removeClass('active').one('transitionend', function() {
        header.removeClass('fixed');
    header.addClass('active');
      });
    }
  }).scroll();

})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);   
    $('.siteHeader').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
header nav, section {
 display: block;
}
.headerNav {
 height: auto; 
 float: right;
 margin: 0px;
}
.headerNav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 40px;
}
.siteHeader.fixed .branding img {
 height: 55px;
 margin: 5px 25px;
}
.siteHeader {
 height: 86px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 11;
 background-color: transparent;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
 transition: transform .3s;
 -moz-transform: translateY(-86px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-86px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-86px);
 transform: translateY(-86px);
}
.siteHeader.fixed {
 width: 100%;
 height: 66px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: #000;
 -moz-transform: translateY(-130px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-130px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-130px);
 transform: translateY(-130px);
 transition: transform .3s;
}
.siteHeader.active {
 -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
 transform: translateY(0px);
 transition: transform .3s;
}
.siteHeader.fixed.active {
 -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
 transform: translateY(0px);
 transition: transform .3s;
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
 .siteHeader{
  display: none; 
 } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="siteHeader">    
  <nav class="headerNav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>   
 </nav>  
</div>
<div style="height: 1500px;">content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this stack

```
(function($) {
  var header = $('.siteHeader');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
      header.addClass('fixed active').off('transitionend');     
    } else if (header.hasClass('active')) {
      header.removeClass('active').one('transitionend', function() {
        header.removeClass('fixed');
          header.addClass('active');
      });
    }
  }).scroll();

})(jQuery);

$(window).resize(function() {     
    $('.siteHeader').addClass('active');
    $('.siteHeader').removeClass('fixed');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);   
    $('.siteHeader').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a second event listener to your function to also check for resize:

```
$(window).on('scroll', 'resize', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
    header.addClass('fixed active').off('transitionend');       
  } else if (header.hasClass('active')) {
    header.removeClass('active').one('transitionend', function() {
      header.removeClass('fixed');
      header.addClass('active');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: it broke it completly